# WinUI3, WASDK: Cannot add Input.Toggle into CarouselPage

Tags: c#, winui-3, windows-app-sdk

I try creating Windows 11 [widgets](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/develop/widgets/widget-providers). But have problems with writing templates.
I need Carousel with checkboxes, it should looks like this:

```
"type": "Carousel",
"height": "stretch",
"rtl": false,
"pages": [
{
    "type": "CarouselPage",
    "id": "firstPage",
    "items": [
             {
                 "type": "Input.Toggle",
                 "title": "Title 1",
             }],
             "rtl": false
             },
             {
     "type": "CarouselPage",
     "id": "secondPage",
     "items": [
              {
                  "type": "Input.Toggle",
                  "title": "Title 2",
               }],
               "rtl": false
}
]
```

But I get error: [Parse] Element type "Input.Toggle" is not allowed in this context.
I cannot found any useful docs for widgets, there is no Carousel control in [Schema Explorer](https://adaptivecards.io/explorer/Input.Toggle.html). I don`t have any ideas.

I am try use Input.Toggle inside Container - it did not help.

Comment: You can't put `Input.Toggle` inside the Carousel. You could use the [Adaptive Card Designer](https://www.adaptivecards.io/designer/) to design and check your template first.

Comment: @RoyLi-MSFT What type of elements can be placed in Carousel? Microsoft ToDo use Carousel with toggles (https://imgur.com/a/EyPYyhZ). How?

Comment: The image you share seems not be to a Carousel.